# how to intersect multiple Maps (dictionary) in Dart

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart, dictionary

I have a List consisting of multiple Maps (Dictionaries) regardless of the value of each element in the map

```
var list = [{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':7},
            {'J':8, 'b':2, 'e':2},
            {'l':1, 'b':3, 'r':4},
            {'u':9, 'k':7} ];
```

Note that I don't know how many maps the list will have. It could be 0 and could be 1000 (I read from a JSON file).

I want to intersect them so the output would be like this:

```
var res = 'b';
```

I've done it in python by using this method:

```
res = set.intersection(*map(set, list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would do the trick. It folds the list by intersecting the map keys one by one.

```dart
final list = [
  {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 7},
  {'J': 8, 'b': 2, 'e': 2},
  {'l': 1, 'b': 3, 'r': 4},
  {'u': 9, 'b': 7}
];

final res = list.fold<Set<String>>(
  list.first.keys.toSet(),
  (result, map) => result.intersection(map.keys.toSet()),
);

print(res); // Prints: {b}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but it's not working unless all the maps have one common key.
I intentionally put the last map in my question witch doesn't include 'b'
Any suggestions ?

Comment: An intersection between all of them without a key in common would be always an empty result. Are you sure you want the intersection? Maybe it's the most common one, no?

Comment: Yes, indeed. BTW, in Python, the result of an intersection would be always empty if there is no key in common between the maps the same way as in Dart.

Comment: maybe the most common, but the intersection function in python did it.  
in python it's much easier and straightforward, the code mentioned in the question do the intersection and return a list of intersected keys (could return more than one)
is it possible to implement it dart?

Comment: If you try the exact list you've posted in Python it doesn't work if you're asking for the intersection. It doesn't make any sense to intersect sets that don't have anything in common.

Comment: I think i got it now, thanks a lot, this was helpful.